# UNIX script date extract

Tags: unix, logging

I'm doing a UNIX script that goes through a log file and outputs the hosts from which web connections have occurred. I achieve this with the following script

```
if [ "$1" = "hosts" ]; then
 grep "$2" $logs | awk '{print $1}' | uniq > templist

 lines=`wc templist | awk '{print $1}'`
 while [ "$number" -le "$lines" ]
  do
   hostip=`sed -n "$number p" templist`
   `nslookup -sil "$hostip" | grep -i "name" | awk '{print $4}' >> lookup` 
   number=`expr $number + 1`
 done 

 echo " "
 echo " Host IP Address "
 echo " --------------- "

 paste templist lookup
 rm lookup
 rm templist
 exit 1
fi
```

However, by me I can't figure out how to output the dates as well. I've tried something along the lines of:

```
if [ "$1" = "hostsdate" ]; then
 grep "$2" $logs | awk '{print $1}'| uniq > templist
 grep "$2" $logs | awk '{print $4,$5}'| uniq > datelist

 lines=`wc templist | awk '{print $1}'`
 while [ "$number" -le "$lines" ]
  do
   hostip=`sed -n "$number p" templist`
   `nslookup -sil  "$hostip" | grep -i "name" | awk '{print $4}' >> lookup` 
   number=`expr $number + 1`
 done 

 echo " "
 echo " Access Date                   Host IP Address  Host Name   "
 echo " ---------------------------------------------------------  "

 paste templist lookup >final
 paste datelist final
 rm lookup
 rm templist
 rm final
 rm datelist
 exit 1
fi
```

But that didn't work.... the format of the log file I'm working with is as follows:

153.35.83.237 - - [05/Oct/1997:01:10:48 +0100] "GET /User/G.N.James/netzee/Dice.class HTTP/1.0" 304 -

153.35.83.237 - - [05/Oct/1997:01:10:49 +0100] "GET /User/G.N.James/netzee/Board.class HTTP/1.0" 304 -

153.35.83.237 - - [05/Oct/1997:01:10:50 +0100] "GET /User/G.N.James/netzee/Title.class HTTP/1.0" 304 -

153.35.83.237 - - [05/Oct/1997:01:10:51 +0100] "GET /User/G.N.James/netzee/JavaButton.class HTTP/1.0" 304 -

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This does a search through every line and returns something like what you want:

```
awk '{ print $1,$4,$5 }' access_log | while read ip dt1 dt2
do
        echo $dt1 $dt2 $ip `host $ip | awk '{ print $5}'`
done
```

...however, I'm trying to work out exactly what output you're trying to get? Are you wanting the latest date/time for every IP? I notice you're doing a uniq on values - trying to work out why that is or is it simply to reduce the number of lookups performed? If this latter, then you can do this:

```
TMPFILE=hosts.$$
LOGFILE=x.log

echo 'Creating lookup tempfile...'
awk '{ print $1 }' $LOGFILE | sort | uniq | while read ip
do
        echo $ip `host $ip | awk '{ print $5 }'`
done > $TMPFILE

echo 'Date/host report...'
awk '{ print $1,$4,$5 }' $LOGFILE | uniq | while read ip dt1 dt2
do
        echo $dt1 $dt2 $ip `grep "^$ip" $TMPFILE | awk '{ print $2 }'`
done

rm $TMPFILE
```

There may be a better way again (e.g., with perl) - it depends entirely on the size of the logfile you're processing. If this is likely to become a large file, then delegating some of the work to perl may be worth doing as then stuff like the temporary file I've used above can actually be held in an in-memory hash, improving performance again.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying to reduce the number of lookups. I went with the first approach. Also I've noticed that you're using host instead of nslookup. Is that to get around the nslookup address resolution errors?

Comment: I use host simply because it's default output is easier to parse as it just kicks out a single line :-)